# Firebase Query Database returns null for username

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query this database:

[image]

I am using this line of code:

```
databaseReference.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "billsmith").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
    print(snap)
})
```

This line of code returns null - meaning it did not find "jondoe" as a username in the users node. How do I get this to work?

Comment: `byChild: "usernames"` should be `byChild: "username"` to match database

Comment: That was a typo - thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. the type `usernames` vs `username`
2. you're trying to query a deeper property, but only present the property name instead of its path

This should work better:

```
databaseReference
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "userDetails/username")
  .queryEqual(toValue: "billsmith")
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
    print(snap)
  })
```

Comment: I made a few typos in the code in my question so I edited the answer by adding .child("users") but that works, thanks! Is there a place for me to learn more about queries? I was having trouble with finding some of the docs on querying.

Comment: If the documentation isn't helpful enough, I'd recommend looking around Stack Overflow for related questions. There must have been quite a few of them by now.